# swiftui - how to detect mouse hover over element in picker and present a popover

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'd like to show a popover when the user hovers over an element in the picker.

It doesn't work, it seems that the picker is grabbing the hover and not passing it through.

I've also tried adding a button to the right side of the text and then when pressing it showing the popover, but the picker won't show the button when there is an `HStack` holding each row and each button

Code is very standard:

```
struct MyView: View {
 @State var selected = .....
 @State var hovered = false // also tried setting this to true always for tests
 var body: some View {
  Picker("", selection: $selection) {
    ForEach(states) { s in
      Text("\(s.id)").popover(isPresented: $hovered) {
          Text("this is hovered")           
      }.onHover { (hover) in 
         hovered = hover
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested on device?

Comment: it's a mac app so yes

Comment: Hi ... did you find a solution for this?

Comment: abandoned it. Perhaps you can manually track the position and do the calculations independently?